# How can I temporarily set the signature of (Replies/Forwards) to None?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Is it possible to temporarily set the signature of (Replies/Forwards) to None using VBA or [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) setting?

I mean at beginning of the `Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd` to set the signature of (Replies/Forwards) to **None** and at end revert it to my previous signature.

[image]

```
Public WithEvents objInbox As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem

    If Not TypeOf item Is MailItem Then Exit Sub

    Set objMail = item
    Set objForward = objMail.Forward

    'Customize the forward subject, body and recipients'
    With objForward
        .Recipients.Add ("abcde@yahoo.com")
        .Recipients.ResolveAll
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you want writing anything in the forwarded mail body? If I remember well, I played with the issue some time ago, but I couldn't find a way to do it by simple changing a specific property. I used to `Display` the mail before sending, to search for signature (if it exists) using a specific bookmark, delete it and send only after that...

Comment: @FaneDuru I intended to wrote this comment before seeing your answer. Yes the disadvantage of using `objForward.Display` is the screen flickering.

Comment: I am afraid that **Outlook Object Model does not expose signatures at all**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The courtesy of this [answer by Dmitry Streblechenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820937/how-to-temporally-set-signature-of-replies-forwards-to-be-none/74828769#74828769).

I just added a workaround (API Message Box) to his code to make it fully workable.

First, you need to download Redemption [Link](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm) and install it , either by run install.exe or register its Dll.

This part of code will be put on **ThisOutlookSession** module:

```
    Dim Account As Variant
    Static Signature As Variant

    Dim Session As Object: Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")  'Late Binding
   'Dim Session As New Redemption.RDOSession                                    'Early Binding

    Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
     Set Account = Session.Accounts.GetOrder(2).Item(1)     'First mail account
      Set Signature = Account.ReplySignature
       Account.ReplySignature = Nothing
       Account.Save

     Call MsgBoxTimeout(0, "This MsgBox will close by itself", "", vbInformation, 0, 1)
'_____________

     'Do other code here
'_____________

      Account.ReplySignature = Signature      'Restore Reply_Forward Signature
      Account.Save
```

**Note:** you have to put this API declaration on a separate module other than ThisOutlookSession

```
Public Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, ByVal wlange As Long, ByVal dwTimeout As Long) As Long
```

Comment: When Redemption modifies the account settings, the notification is sent to Outlook (via a Windows message) and it knows to clear its cache and reload the data. For the notification to go through, the app (Outlook) must be idle so that is Windows message pump (GetMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMesage) runs. And that happens only when Outlook sits idle, which happens if you show a dialog box and wait for it to close

Answer (score 2):

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), you can use [IOlkAccountManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/iolkaccountmanager) interface to set the new/reply signatures. They are stored as properties on the [IOlkAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/iolkaccount) object. You can see them in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click IOlkAccountManager button and the double click on the corresponding account:

[image]

If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can use [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language; I am also its author). It exposes New and Reply signatures on the [RDOAccount](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm) object:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Account = Session.Accounts.GetOrder(2).Item(1) 'first mail account
if Not (Account Is Nothing) Then
  set Signature = Account.ReplySignature
  Account.ReplySignature = Nothing
  Account.Save
  ' do something
  ' then restore the reply signature
  Account.ReplySignature = Signature
  Account.Save
End If
```

Comment: Please, I couldn't find on internet any download link for `IOlkAccountManager` , could you provide it.

Comment: IOlkAccountManager (see the link above) is not a downlodable library, it is an interface exposed by Outlook (MAPI) and is accessible in C++ or Delphi only.

Comment: I solved the above error by `Dim Session As Object, Account As Variant, Signature As Variant`, But the main issue still exists (Signature is added to the auto-forwarded emails).

Comment: If you don't restore the signature back, does Outlook show in the options that there is no signature set for the primary email account?

Comment: I debugged the code (line by line) and found that the signature as it is and never changed by your code .

Comment: So it never gets reset when your code explicitly sets it to Nothing?

Comment: Try to add `Account.Save` after `Account.ReplySignature = Nothing`

Comment: Your answer is close to be accepted but there are still some issues.
I added `Account.Save` after `Account.ReplySignature = Nothing` and that is effectively set signature to None ,
But the signature did not reset after code finished, So I Added also `Account.Save` after `Account.ReplySignature = Signature` and that restored the signature correctly.

Comment: Now, If I run the full code (Line by Line by debugging F8) It works flawlessly,
But if I let it run automatically then the expected result is not achieved (signature is added to the forwarded message).
I could not find a direct method to use `Wait or Sleep` on **ThisOutlookSession**, So I added `MsgBox` after the first `Account.Save` and that fixed the full issues.
Kindly advise me what I should do now?

Comment: I found a direct way to use sleep inside **ThisOutlookSession**, But It did not fix the issue.
only using `MsgBox` managed to solve my issues. I am afraid, but kindly advice

Comment: MAPI account change notifications are implemented via Windows messages, which means the Windows message pump needs to run for a notification to go through. Doe your code display any other UI?

Comment: My code dose not display any other UI. I replaced (VBA MsgBox) by API MsgBox **(It auto close itself)**, This also fixed all issues. I still do not understand the reason behind that

Comment: When Redemption modifies the account settings, the notification is sent to Outlook (via a Windows message) and it knows to clear its cache and reload the data. For the notification to go through, the app (Outlook) must be idle so that is Windows message pump (GetMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMesage) runs. And that happens only when Outlook sits idle, which happens if you show a dialog box and wait for it to close.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, the next suggested solution delete signature, if exists...

Please, copy the next sub in the project dealing with Outlook forward automation:

```
Sub ClearSignature(oMail As Object)
        Dim objWdEd As Object, oBjBookM As Object
        Set objWdEd = oMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        On Error GoTo NoSignature
        Set oBjBookM = objWdEd.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
          oBjBookM.Range.Delete
          Exit Sub
        
NoSignature:
        Debug.Print "No Any Signature found..." 'it may be commented...
End Sub
```

The following part of your code should be adapted as:

```
 'your existing code...
       With objForward
            .Recipients.Add ("abcde@yahoo.com")
            .Recipients.ResolveAll
            'inserted lines _______________________
              .Display 'to load signature, if any...
              ClearSignature objForward  'to clear the signature (if any)
             '_____________________________________
            .Send
        End With
 'your existing code
```

The suggested solution has the disadvantage if screen flickering (display it for short time, before sending), in case of mass forwarding...

Comment: I use this solution and can confirm works, as an OT: I use `oBjBookM.Windows(1).Selection.Delete`, what is the difference against `oBjBookM.Range.Delete`?

Comment: You have more experience than me, I found the below Page about `Outlook Signature Registry Settings` , I tried manually to change the cited value in registry and it works (but after close outlook and open it again) , if you still interested to help   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f9fd782e-ecdb-41e1-b00a-0b4b2cfd7d32/outlook-signature-registry-settings?forum=outlook

Comment: @Leedo I am in vacation and no laptop available...

Comment: @Sgdva I have no idea about what `oBjBookM.Windows(1).Selection` means. But I know that `oBjBookM.Range` means the range of the found signature bookmark which has to be deleted...

Comment: @Leedo I would like to be sure that I've got you... I know how to check if a registry key exists, modify or delete it, but Outlook will never use the modified Registry status before closing and reopening it. Using an automation from Excel, an open Outlook can be found, close it, modify the necessary registry keys, reopening it and running the mass replaying code. Would that be convenient? It is possible that a friend come tonight with a laptop. If convenient and found some time I can try supplying a solution. ..

Comment: @FaneDuru Firstly,happy vacation. All automation are related only to outlook. to save your efforts, the updated answer by "Dmitry Streblechenko" is very close to my needs (actually it works by a workaround)