# Choose Reply Signature

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-redemption

I have manually created a signature in outlook with name `“Microsoft”`.
I need to change Reply Signature to cited one.
I have installed **Redemption** and used the below code ,But I got `Type Mismatch` at this line `Account.ReplySignature = "Microsoft"`

```
Sub Change_Signature()
 
    Dim Account As Variant
    Dim Session As Object
   Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
     Set Account = Session.Accounts.GetOrder(2).Item(1)   'First mail account
       Account.ReplySignature = "Microsoft"
       Account.Save
End Sub
```

As always, Thanks for all help.

Comment: According to this post the signature is not exposed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820937/how-to-temporally-set-signature-of-replies-forwards-to-be-none

Comment: Try using `Option Explicit` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Comment: Get the Informed badge - take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. `Account.ReplySignature` is an object! So, it must be set, it cannot be a string (`Signature.name`)...
2. In order to benefit of VBA Intellisense in the discussed case, I would like to suggest you to firstly set a reference to 'Redemption Outlook and MAPI Com library'. Since you try using `Redemption` you certainly registered the Com object...
3. Declare variables in a way to see what properties/methods do they expose:

```
  Dim Account As RDOAccount, Session As RDOSession, Signature As RDOSignature
```

4. Use the next function able to return a session signature object by its name:

```
Function setSignature(strSign As String, Account As RDOAccount) As Redemption.RDOSignature
    Dim Signature As RDOSignature
    For Each Signature In Account.Session.Signatures
        If Signature.Name = strSign Then
            Set setSignature = Signature: Exit Function
        End If
     Next
End Function
```

5. Use the next adapted code:

```
Sub Change_Signature()
    Dim Account As RDOAccount, Session As RDOSession, Signature As RDOSignature
    Const signName As String = "IV_Signature"
    
    Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
      Set Account = Session.Accounts.GetOrder(2).Item(1)   'First mail account
      Set Signature = setSignature(signName, Account)
      If Account.ReplySignature Is Nothing Then
            Set Account.ReplySignature = Signature
            Account.Save: MsgBox "Changed to """ & signName & """!"
     Else
            If Signature.Name <> Account.ReplySignature.Name Then
                    Set Account.ReplySignature = Signature
                    Account.Save: MsgBox "Changed to """ & signName & """!"
            Else
                    MsgBox "This account already usess signature """ & signName & """..."
            End If
     End If
End Sub
```

The above code can be adapted to use late binding, but you can only use it, without being able to see the rest of used objects properties, methods in case of future needs/developments... Then, early binding is always faster then late. In this very case this aspect does not matter too much, but it is good to have it in your mind, I think.

Of course, there are ways to improve it, for instance to determine if used signature name was misspelled... In such a case `Signature` will be `Nothing`, so `If Signature is Nothing then MsgBox "Wrong signature string...": Exit Sub`.

Comment: I changed **signName** to my desired signature “Microsoft”.
I got Compile error:Variable not defined @ `Set Signature` ,then I declared Signature as RDOSignature (fixed this part).
Then I run and got error **Object variable or With block variable not set** at this line `If Signature.Name <> Account.ReplySignature.Name Then`

Comment: I found out that the above error ( in my comment) is raised if outlook Reply/forwards signature was set to none.

Comment: @Leedo I did not test it for this case... Anyhow, please use `Option Explicit` on top of the module. Otherwise, it should rise an error. I adapted the code to also check if the signature name is the existing one and forgot to adapt the declaration, too.  I adapted it now. No time to test the best way of checking the case you mentioned, but it should be easy... Otherwise, doesn't it do what you need?

Comment: @Leedo Adapted the code to also handle the case of `None` set signature...

Comment: @FaneGuru - yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, I can see it - I've been using late binding in VBA way too much :-)