# How to change outlook signatures automatically?

Tags: outlook, email-signature

How to change email signatures automatically in outlook? I would like to change signatures in bulk in an automated way.

I need to switch Outlook signatures automatically.

Comment: Do you mean add new signatures / modify existing ones, or assign existing signatures as new/reply signatures for a particular Exchange account?

Comment: I'm from a corporate network and I need to change the already demanding passwords for all employees. I need to do this without being machine by machine, I would like to do it all at once

Answer (score 0):

See [Choose Reply Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001702/choose-reply-signature) to see how new or reply signature can be set.

Note that signatures are not programmatically exposed at all in the Outlook Object Model. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728029/332059 for a discussion on how the signatures are stored. Since they are stored locally in the profile section, they can only be accessed locally, you cannot do that remotely for other users.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide much for dealing with signatures. You can find the various files that make up your Outlook signatures in one of the following locations:

- Windows 10 and later:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures
```

- Older versions of Windows drive:

```
\Documents and Settings\[user]\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures
```

Typically, a signature consists of three files and a folder:

- `<signature_name>.htm` - This file is used when creating HTML messages.
- `<signature_name>.rtf` - This file is used when creating Rich Text messages.
- `<signature_name>.txt` - This file is used when creating Plain Text message.
- `<signature_name>_files` - This folder is used to store supporting files for your signature such as formatting, images and/or business cards (vcf-files).

So, if signatures are set in Outlook you can access these folders and files and change them without relying on Outlook or Extended MAPI (Redemption).

Comment: `Signatures` folder name is localized

Comment: Ideally, the path to the signatures folder should be read from the windows registry.